# Calling getUserPrincipal in SecurityFilter led to IllegalStateException:Handshake is not completed

Tags: https, jersey, grizzly, userprincipal

I just tried to use Jersey 1.16 and add https support in my application.
Using [Jersey https_grizzly example](http://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/show/trunk/jersey/samples/https-clientserver-grizzly/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/samples/https_grizzly) as a reference, I added a line of code in the SecurityFilter.authority()

```
final Principal principal = request.getSecurityContext().getUserPrincipal();
if (principal != null){
    System.out.println("principal: " + principal.getName());
} else {
System.out.println("No principal") ;
}
```

Then I tried to start the server using https and setNeedClientAuth to false to avoid using client side certificate by changing Server.java in startServer():

```
webServer = GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(
                getBaseURI(),
                null,
                true,
                new SSLEngineConfigurator(sslContext).setClientMode(false).setNeedClientAuth(false)
        );
```

the boolean parameter in setNeedClientAuth(false) is originally true in order to request client certificate.
I think in this way my application can adapt to client with and without a certificate. When without a certificate, the getUserPrincipal() may return null so that I know this is an anonymous user.
Unfortunately, in this case, the system raises an exception as following and the client received nothing:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handshake is not completed!
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLFilter.accurateWrite(SSLFilter.java:569)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLFilter.handleWrite(SSLFilter.java:216)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$8.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:265)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:134)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:78)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.write(FilterChainContext.java:652)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.io.OutputBuffer.writeContentBuffer0(OutputBuffer.java:908)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.io.OutputBuffer.flushBinaryBuffers(OutputBuffer.java:893)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.io.OutputBuffer.flushAllBuffers(OutputBuffer.java:864)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.io.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:678)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NIOOutputStreamImpl.flush(NIOOutputStreamImpl.java:91)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletOutputStreamImpl.flush(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:101)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent$Writer.flush(WebComponent.java:315)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse$CommittingOutputStream.flush(ContainerResponse.java:145)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.writeToAsString(ReaderWriter.java:191)
at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeToAsString(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:128)
at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:88)
at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:58)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1479)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:147)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.FilterChainImpl.invokeFilterChain(FilterChainImpl.java:106)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.doServletService(ServletHandler.java:252)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.service(ServletHandler.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:164)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandlerChain.service(HttpHandlerChain.java:196)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:164)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:265)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:134)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:78)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:815)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:567)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:547)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Why I couldn't use getUserPrincipal() in this case? Does somebody know about it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling getUserPrincipal() will perform a renegotiation requesting that the client provide a certificate chain.  In this case, the ssl layer is raising an exception that the cert chain is null, however, Grizzly isn't throwing the exception (and it probably should).  Because it doesn't throw it, the SSLEngine is left an in incorrect state leading to the exception you have described above.

I've logged an [issue](http://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1397) to better handle this case.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.
So how can I find out if the client-side has a certificate or not in case of needClientAuth=false ?

Comment: That's a good question.  This behavior has been present for years.  I'd like to request that you open an issue for this and we can continue the discussion there.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have created a new issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280008/how-can-i-find-out-if-the-client-has-a-certificate-in-case-of-needclientauth-fal).